# Has anyone else encountered a malignant file named "card.php"?

Tags: php, wordpress

A client of mine recently had their WordPress site hacked.
Nothing major at first - a Google Ad inserted into the content of a page - apparently through the admin area.
But - going through the site I found an unknown file in the root folder named card.php, which is apparently used to get info from the system.
Does this ring a bell with anyone?
What I'm wondering is: Has my FTP been compromised or did the malignant code get in through some other backdoor (such as a WordPress security breach)? And what is the best way to prevent this from happening on any other site?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way to know if it's malicious is to have a look at the code in the file. The filename may or may not be relevant, you should try to identify where the code comes from.

Comment: The more likely answer is that a theme / plugin is vulnerable leading to shell / file upload access. Make sure you delete any plugins you are not using and google search ones that you are to check for vulnerabilities.

Comment: you can find glich by server access log and then fix it that back door

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your website is effected by some vulnerability. Below you can find some useful tips to make your website safe.

- Of course delete **card.php** from root of the WordPress, because it doesn't exists in WordPress.
- Change WordPress for admin (and all users with admin access).
- Change FTP and CPanel credentials to be safe for future.
- Replace **wp-admin** and **wp-includes** folders from latest fresh WordPress source code.
- Configure one of the security plugins for WordPress. For example :

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulletproof-security/

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/
- Once you have made website secure, install https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ and find which files are affected.
- You can remove those effected code manually and make it clean.
- If you are using free plugins from WordPress directory, just replace effected plugin to the new updated version.
- Follow procedure for themes.
- Make sure to keep all plugins and themes updated to latest version.
- You must have to update WordPress version to latest version to minimize security risks.

**Note** :- There may be many other solutions, i have shared what i am following every time i face same situation.

Comment: Thanks @Milap - lots of very useful ideas. I cleaned out a lot of files, and am trying out Wordfence now. It looks really promising.

Comment: @Bonfils, ok try after sometime.